# How do i add a Static Library to Android Studio?

Tags: android, maven, static-libraries

I've been trying to integrate this  [Midi Lib](https://github.com/LeffelMania/android-midi-lib) to my Android project without success. I've tried by manual importing it , linking it the same as this 
[lib](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio) but it's giving me compile errors. 
I've also tried maven with no luck.

Error when adding the library as an external module (Added to libs folder in root of my project)

> Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libs:android-midi-lib-master.

my settings gradle :

```
include ':app'
include 'libs:android-midi-lib-master'
```

My build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
    compile project(':libs:android-midi-lib-master')
    compile files('libs/wekaSTRIPPED.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: "it's giving me compile errors" -- nobody can help you with those errors without a [mcve], which would include the Java code that is giving the errors, along with the actual error messages.

Comment: It's because there are no instructions on how to import that library, it says that it doesn't have any Android-specific dependencies or considerations , but they do not specify how do i add it . There is no even a .jar.

Comment: Download the Java code. Either add it directly to your existing Android Studio `app/` module. Or create a new library module, put the Java code in that library module, and then add a `compile project(...)` dependency in your `app/` module to depend upon the library module.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've added some information about my errors. I've tried that way and it's giving me "declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libs:android-midi-lib-master." 
First time having trouble importing a library.

Comment: I recommend either moving the module out of `libs/`, getting rid of `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`, or doing something to ensure that you're not winding up trying to get this JAR twice or something.

Comment: How about a simple `compile 'com.github.leffelmania:android-midi-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT'` in the `dependencies` of your `build.gradle`? (Maven is in your repositories, right?)

Comment: @KalaBalik i tried your way before submitting this question . I've already added mavenCentral to my projects gradle, however it seems that it's not finding the lib . "Failed to resolve: com.github.leffelmania:android-midi-lib:1.0-SNAPSHOT"

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the create a new folder leff in my module . Then replace all occurrences of com.leff.midi with the my package name which in my case was com.benidobre.android.midi. After that no more import errors and I was able to run the app